# How to keep converted field in UpdateCommand statement from being overwritten by same UpdateCommand statement?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, gridview, sql-server-2012

I'm in the process of creating a report that counts how many times in a given week records were updated.

Sounds easy, right?  Let me throw some complexity in with this challenge.

The challenge I'm facing is that the date ranges I'm using are dependent on another field and if that gets updated, it will up the date range field throwing the reporting off completely.  I'll try to keep this as simple as possible with the example below:

So I have a table

```
book.book_keeping_2014
```

In this table are the following columns:

```
record_number - Automatically generated by a SEQUENCE command
amount
record_name
record_updated
```

The records in the database already exist and ideally be updated only once.

The record name has a specific format where the date preceeds the rest of the file information.  A sample file name would be:

```
20140106-blah-blah-blah-blah.txt
```

So here's what I have defined for the UpdateCommand:

```
UPDATE book.book_keeping_2014 SET [amount] = @amount, 
record_name = @record_name, record_updated = LEFT(record_name,8)  
WHERE [record_number] = @record_number
```

So this entry in the record_name field -

```
20140106-blah-blah-blah-blah(etc).txt
```

Would be entered into the record_updated field as:

```
20140106
```

As it stands the code works fine.  However, there may be the odd time where a given cell in the record_name column that would need to be updated.  Based on the UpdateCommand above, if the record_name field gets updated so will the record_updated field.

The challenge I'm facing is if I'm creating a weekly report for the first week of January  and then I updated the record on the 4th week of January, this would throw off a report.  Same goes for monthly reports.

My question is how can I prevent/re-code my Update statement so that when the LEFT command pulls the correct information the first time it won't get overwritten?

I have similar challenges with a date conversion scenario as well but I may just put that in a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change the structure of your table, then you can add a flag for HasUpdated.  Then in your query, only update rows that HasUpdated = 0.

Comment: You mean add a column called 'HasUpdated' or is this a system setting?

Comment: Add a bit column to the table.  It could be maintained by a trigger that will change the column to a 1 whenever that row is updated or manage it in your `UPDATE` statements.